# Как правильно написать ORM запрос DJANGO

Tags: django, orm

SELECT * FROM category WHERE category.id not in (SELECT category_id from news)

Есть SQL запрос, который нужно переписать для ORM, как - пока не знаю

Задание: Categories, у которых нет соответствия в таблице News

Отношение Categories : News --- ManyToMany

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поиграться с методом `exclude` в queryset. Сначала делаете запрос на все айдишники, которые есть в News. Затем все их исключаете в запросе к Categories.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class News(models.Model):
    category_id = models.IntegerField()
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(to=Categories)

q1 = News.objects.only('category_id').all() #сначала запрос на все category_id из News

query = Categories.objects.exclude(id__in=q1).all() #затем исключить все найденные category_id из Categories
```

Если у вас many2many связь наоборот - в классе Categories, то поменяйте классы в запросах соответственно.

Comment: Уже выполнил это таким образом. Интересны ещё варианты

Comment: У меня как-то была проблема: например, выбрать Изделие, которое состоит как минимум из всех металлов в списке ["металл1", "металл2", "металл3"]. То есть изделие должно включать и металл1, и 2, и 3 - всё вместе, а lookup-метод "in" ищет хотя бы 1 совпадение. Помогли Q-запросы. Типо такого: `.exclude(~reduce(and_, [Q(metall__name=c) for c in metalls_values]))`, где mettals_values - список названий металлов.